# CentOS - Java in Browser

Tags: linux, centos, java

My output of `java -version`

```
[root@CentOS ~]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_30"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (rhel-5.1.13.3.el6_5-i386)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

It says I need the Java Runtime environment plugin installed to run in my browser
So I run `yum install jre.i586`, (Java(TM) Platform Standard Edition Runtime Environment) and this is the output

```
[root@CentOS ~]# yum install jre.i586
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.easynews.com
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * extras: mirrors.xmission.com
 * updates: centos.sonn.com
Setting up Install
Nothing to do
```

Does this mean it's already installed? I still can't run Java in my browser.

Comment: How did you install Java in the first place? Try running `yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk`

Comment: I just did yum install java. And It works now. Thank you. Post your comment as an answer so I can mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to run either

`yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk`

or, even more simply, as you said,

`yum install java`